# Would removing an interior brick facia reduce foundation settling?

Tags: fireplace

We've got a 16ft by 8ft wide fireplace. The brick facia inside the house has been slowly detaching from the wall and we have some drywall cracking around windows on each side of the fireplace. We don't really like the look so we were planning on putting up molding to either cover the brick or removing the brick and doing molding/casework on a wood frame.

My thought is removing the brick would help decrease the weight that may be causing any additional settling on this 35 year old house. Thoughts? Am I over thinking it? Assuming the wood beam is tied into the wall and not supported by the brick work.

[image: wall separation]

[image: fireplace]

[image: window crack]

Comment: Welcome. I've attempted to simplify and clarify your title question. Feel free to revise further, and take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: Molding/moulding.  My autocorrect can get weird sometimes.

Comment: In your bottom image, is that some kind of paper debonding from the ceiling just barely to the left of the crack? That one shadow looks darker than the shadows at other ceiling texture mountains. And elsewhere along the wall-ceiling joint, the distorted looking ceiling surface is just inconsistently applied texture? Or something more interesting?

Comment: Yes that is the tape joint cracking. The ceiling is just inconsistently applied texture.

Comment: The cracked drywall could just be poor workmanship on the taping. The cracks look a little too jagged for that, though. The symmetry on both sides of the chimney seems to contradict the workmanship theory, but the bad spots are also the high spots. Poor access for the drywallers could have caused consistently poor workmanship at that elevation. Still a flimsy theory given the presumably taped ceiling joints.

Comment: No worries, @Spencer, auto-cowreck gets a lot of people. :)

Answer (score 4):

If the cracking above the windows was caused by differential settlement and you're not sitting on a clay with very low permeability (you're probably not), then any settlement that was going to happen has already happened. Changing the weight could only disrupt the new equilibrium and potentially cause more cracking. Removing brick would probably be fine, though, if you prefer how the wall looks without it. Fix the drywall above the windows. If differential settlement was the cause, then it won't crack again. If lateral flexing plus differential settlement caused the cracking, then maybe the lateral flexing alone won't manage to re-crack it.

I suppose there could be a soil bearing capacity problem below the ridge beam's column, where continuing settlement could cause additional cracking. That's very unlikely with typical quality control from 35 years ago. It's side-to-side flexing that has probably caused all of your issues. It will be side-to-side flexing causing any additional issues going forward in time.

The cracking above the windows is probably due to poor detailing or poor construction of the "collectors"/"drag struts" above the windows. Your roof diaphragm picks up wind loading perpendicular to your house's ridge beam. The roof diaphragm then transfers some of that loading to the foundation through the wall in your images. Your window creates a soft spot in the wall. That combined with the short distance between window and ceiling creates high stresses around the top edge of the window that ideally would have been mitigated by some special detailing. Maybe it was (probably not), but some know-it-all construction guy decided that it was silly. Nothing catastrophic, just a superficial problem.

You should check out the deflection limits from [IRC R301.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch03_SecR301.7). Note the "exterior walls—wind loads with flexible finishes" limit of H/120 versus the "lintels supporting masonry veneer walls" limit of L/600. This is why the brick has detached from the wall. The wall isn't nearly stiff enough to maintain continuity.

Comment: What is a "roof diaphragm"? Just not a term I'm familiar with...

Comment: @FreeMan, a "roof diaphragm" is a roof that acts as a diaphragm :). A diaphragm is the generalization of a shear wall (most "wall bracing" under the IRC are shear wall details), where you can use the term for your roof paneling instead of just walls. There's a terminology section in Chapter 2 of https://awc.org/publications/2021-sdpws/. There's a textbook-like introduction at https://www.osbpanel.org/pdf/L350.pdf.

Comment: Huh... interesting. Never heard of that. #TIL

Comment: When you say side-to-side flexing do you mean left-to-right-to-left or toward/away/toward when you are looking at the fireplace? Only asking to clarify since we are likely getting the siding redone and those lower windows removed. At that point I could see about strengthening the plywood exterior sheathing.

Comment: @Spencer, facing the fireplace, the flexing is left-to-right. It's from the wind pushing on the face of house that runs perpendicular to the fireplace wall. Imagine you had a masonry wall in the garden. The most efficient way to brace it against toppling is to install another perpendicular wall. The wall behind your fireplace is analogous to this perpendicular wall. If I wanted to use the L/600 brick limit to compute a deflection limit for the wall to prevent separation, I'd rationally change it to H/1200. I expect that it would require 1000% (not a typo) of its current sheathing thickness.